# Nhibernate query for items that have a Dictionary Property containing value

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I need a way to query in Nhibernate for items that have a Dictionary Property containing value.

Assume:

```
public class Item
{
     public virtual IDictionary<int, string> DictionaryProperty {get; set;}
}
```

and mapping:

```
    public ItemMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.DictionaryProperty)
            .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .AsMap<string>(
                index => index.Column("IDNumber").Type<int>(),
                element => element.Column("TextField").Type<string>().Length(666)
                )
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Join();
    }
```

I want to query all `Item`s that have a dictionary value of "SomeText". The following example in Linq fails:

```
session.Query<Item>().Where(r => r.DictionaryProperty.Any(g => g.Value == "SomeText"))
```

with error

```
cannot dereference scalar collection element: Value
```

So is there any way to achieve that in NHibernate? Linq is not an exclusive requirement but its preffered. Not that I'm not interested to query over dictionary **keys** that can be achieved using `.ContainsKey` . Φορ [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683365/nhibernate-queryover-the-values-of-a-dictionarymap) is similar but not the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handling `IDictionary<TValueType, TValueType>` would usually bring more issues than advantages. One way, **workaround**, is to introduce a new object *(I will call it MyWrapper)* with properties `Key` and `Value` *(just an example naming)*.

This way we have to 1) create new object (MyWrapper), 2) adjust the mapping and that's it. No other changes... *so the original stuff (mapping, properties) will work, because we would use different (readonly) property for querying*

```
public class MyWrapper
{
    public virtual int Key { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The Item now has

```
public class Item
{
    // keep the existing for Insert/Updae
    public virtual IDictionary<int, string> DictionaryProperty {get; set;}

    // map it
    private IList<MyWrapper> _properties = new List<MyWrapper>();

    // publish it as readonly
    public virtual IEnumerable<MyWrapper> Properties
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<MyWrapper>(_properties); }
    }
}
```

Now we will extend the mapping:

```
HasMany(x => x.Properties)
    .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Component(c =>
    {
        c.Map(x => x.Key).Column("IDNumber")
        c.Map(x => x.Value).Column("TextField")
    })
    ...
    ;
```

And the Query, which will work as expected:

```
session
    .Query<Item>()
    .Where(r => 
        r.Properties.Any(g => g.Value == "SomeText")
    )
```

*NOTE: From my experience, this **workaround** should not be workaround. It is preferred way. NHibernate supports lot of features, but working with Objects brings more profit*

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I didnt even think about it. Once I actually use it and confirm it I will confirm answer and try to also award some bounty for it

Comment: If this would work for you, great. Do not give up to use NHibernate, it is amazing tool. Not as easy to learn, but... so powerful once it is "fully under control" ;)

Comment: After a glorious fight with the beast that is "composite key and also foreign key" I managed to get rid of the dictionary completely and just use the concrete value wrapper, thanks again

Comment: Great, simply great. Enjoy the NHibernate... amazing tool